# How to make this code more simple or shorten?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this code below for displaying a chart. My problem here is that the `labels` and `datasets` are static not dynamic. Can this be possible to make dyanmic?.

```
var globalNewData = "";
function ChartDataLabel() {
    var barChartData = {
        labels: [globalNewData[0]["CandidateName"], globalNewData[1]["CandidateName"],
        globalNewData[2]["CandidateName"], globalNewData[3]["CandidateName"],
        globalNewData[4]["CandidateName"]],
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: "rgba(0,100,0,1)",
            strokeColor: "black",
            data: [globalNewData[0]["Votes"], globalNewData[1]["Votes"], globalNewData[2]["Votes"],
            globalNewData[3]["Votes"], globalNewData[4]["Votes"]] // Votes = Number of Votes
        }]
    }
    //var index = 11;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        barValueSpacing: 2
    });
}

NewData();
function NewData() {
    var url = '../Controller/_NewData'
    var res = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        // async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var Data = response.data;
            globalNewData = Data;
            ChartDataLabel();

        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error");
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult _NewData()
    {
        var Data = new List<object>();
        Data = (from a in db.Testings
                select new
                {
                    TestID = a.TestID,
                    CandidateName = a.Candidatename,
                    Position = a.Position,
                    Votes = a.NoOfVotes
                }).ToList<object>();

        return Json(new
       {
           data = Data
       }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

What I mean in Static is as you can see in the chart code `[globalNewData[0]["CandidateName"]` It is fix(5) in how many data will be display in the chart. In Dynamic even it add new data it will add the array inside `[6]...` for example.

Any suggestion will be accepted.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean when you say you want the `labels` / `datasets` to be dynamic?

Comment: As a side note, it's probably not best to have `globalNewData`. Why not just pass the data into your function? IE: `ChartDataLabel(response.data);`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli its okay now. Thanks to charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map new arrays for labels and dataset data

Something like:

```
function ChartDataLabel(chartData) {
    var barChartData = {
        labels: chartData.labels,// reference to labels array created below
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: "rgba(0,100,0,1)",
            strokeColor: "black",
            data: chartData.points // reference to points array created below
        }]
    }
    //var index = 11;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        barValueSpacing: 2
    });
}


$.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (response) {

            // object with new arrays need to pass to charting function
            var chartData ={
               labels:[],
               points:[]
            }
            // loop through response data and add to each of labels and points arrays
            response.data.forEach(function(item){
                chartData.labels.push(item.CandidateName);
                chartData.points.push(item.Votes);
            })
            // pass chartData into function
            ChartDataLabel(chartData);
       }
  })
```

There are numerous other methods that could be used to map these new arrays also that would reduce code needed even more. I used a longer method for better understanding

---

Alternative would be to do this mapping on server and send data from server so `response.data` contains the labels and points arrays needed

Comment: charlietfl. Can i ask something?. How did the `chartData.labels` display all the datas in the chart?.

Comment: not sure what you mean? `chartData.labels` should be an array with all the labels in it. And similar for `chartData.points`. The structure you sent doesn't match what was needed so these were created and mapped from the data structure you send

Comment: yes I see that it is in array. What I mean is here `labels: chartData.labels,` in chart. If you don't know how.. Its okay ;)

Comment: works no different than assigning an array  manually created in place ... they are both arrays of data

Comment: Thanks. I would like to create new thread for my another problem but I can't because of the rules in time of creating new. :D.